# Multiple factory functions specific to a type OR one generic factory function and then cast to type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm creating a WCF service to act as a DAL for our systems.

Each Db has a class which inherits from interfaces to describe it's functionality e.g.

```
public class <DbName>Service : Database, IProductService, IOrderService
```

If an external system calls a function on the WCF interface e.g.

```
public int CreateProduct(IProduct product, string databaseId)
```

This function needs to interact with a IProductService that is wired to the requested Db, NOT all Databases have the same functionality, some have products other cannot.

Should I have multiple factory functions that can return each type using a switch on the databaseId e.g.

```
public static IProductService GetProductServiceFromConfig(string databaseId)
{
    switch (systemId)
    {
        case DatabaseIds.<DbName>:
            system = new <DbName>Service(new <DbName>ConfigSettings());
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    }
}
```

OR:

One functions that returns an IDatabase that the caller of the function can cast to their desired type e.g.

```
public static IDatabase GetDatabaseServiceFromConfig(string systemId)
{
    // Switch Case and return IDatabase, as each database must inherit from IDatabase
}
```

Function call:

```
var service = DatabaseServiceFactory.GetDatabaseServiceFromConfig(DatabaseIds.<DatabaseName>) as IProductService

if(service != null) { /* The service implements the type IProductService therefore has access to the function you need */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, I've created a solution as follows

```
public static T GetDatabaseServiceFromConfig<T>(string databaseId)
{
    object system = null;

    switch (databaseId)
    {
        case DatabaseIds.<DbName>:
            system = new <DbName>Service(new <DbName>ConfigSettings());
            break;
        // More cases
        default:
            // System not found
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(databaseId);
        }

    if (!(system is T))
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Database type was found and created but does not implement interface: " + typeof(T));
    }

    // Safe cast
    return (T)system;
}
```

Implementation:

```
var service = DatabaseServiceFactory.GetDatabaseServiceFromConfig<IProductService>(DatabaseIds.<DbName>);

// object now has access to functions on IProductService
service.CreateProduct(/*Params*/);
```